# Browser not caching images missing file extension

Tags: php, apache, browser-cache

I have a site where many images are requested from a database. These requests look something like:

```
http://site.com/image/hash121231
```

This returns a 200 OK on the client saying it is not cached even though the underlying type is png, and its header is image/png.

I have this in my httpd.conf

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 12 months"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 12 months"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 12 months"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 week"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 week"
  ExpiresByType text/xml "access plus 1 week"
</IfModule>
```

Now, Images requested like this:

```
http://site.com/static/image.png
```

returns with 304, telling me it is cached.

I have deduced it must be the file extension must be causing the issue. It would be very difficult for me to rewrite chunks of my site to apply the extension to the image request and handle it. Is there any way to have Apache detect the type and append the extension? or could something else be causing this?

**Update**

After following the guide from this site: http://www.hardanswers.net/dynamic-webpage-caching I have got it mostly working.

The only problem now is, the browser seems to use the cache every other request for mostly juts these images. I am not sure if this is behavior of the browser, or something to do with the way the code in the above example is working.

Comment: I assume you have some sort of script serving the images from the database. Apache won't issue the cache control headers for scripts since it has no idea what is being served. You can make this work if you modify your script to include the Cache-control headers when it serves the images.

Comment: Interesting. I was not aware that it handled it that way. Going to go look for some examples on that.